# Python получить случайный ключ в словаре

Tags: python, случайные-числа, dict

Есть словарь как пример:

```js
{
  "morgens": [{
      "morgenmood": {
        "link": "https://github.com/SpyderJabro/SpYD3R/raw/master/assets/morgenchlen/KlipZa10Lyamov-morgenshtern.mp3",
        "name": "Клип за 10 лямов ууууу ыыы"
      }
    },
    {
      "morgenmood": {
        "link": "https://github.com/SpyderJabro/SpYD3R/raw/master/assets/morgenchlen/Morgenshtern-Krasnoe_Vino.mp3",
        "name": "Красное вино"
      }
    },
    {
      "morgenmood": {
        "link": "https://github.com/SpyderJabro/SpYD3R/raw/master/assets/morgenchlen/Morgenshtern-Malyshka.mp3",
        "name": "Малышка"
      }
    },
    {
      "morgenmood": {
        "link": "https://github.com/SpyderJabro/SpYD3R/raw/master/assets/morgenchlen/Morgenshtern-Mne_poh.mp3",
        "name": "Мне пох"
      }
    },
    // ...
  }]
}
```

как отсюда *Рандомно* вытаскивать ключ

Comment: песня нужна пока-что я потом буду переделывать бд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью такой махинации можно скомбинировать выбор случайного ключа из словаря и скомбинировать для поиска и автора, и песни.

```
import random 

a = { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
random.choice(list(a)) # либо а, либо b, либо с
```

---

```
a = {
  "author_1": [
    { "name": 1 },
    { "name": 2 },
    { "name": 3 },
  ],
  "author_2": [
    { "name": 4 },
    { "name": 5 },
    { "name": 6 },
  ],
}

import random

rand_author = random.choice(list(a)) # Случайный автор
rand_song = random.choice(a[rand_author]) # Случайная песня случайного автора

print(rand_author, rand_song)
```

---

У Вашем случае:

```
import random

song = random.choice(a['morgens'])['morgenmood']

print(song['link']) # случайная ссылка
print(song['name']) # случайное имя
```

Comment: нет, это не совсем то что мне нужно. идея та но реализация не подходит. у меня один автор, и массив песен в ключе morgenmood в нем же лежит ссылка на аудио и название. нужно рандомить этот самый ключ morgenmood так чтобы я потом мог вывести как линк так и название

Comment: я отредачил пост чтобы было понятнее что я хочу

Comment: @SpYd3r, ну все верно. С помощь `random.choice` берете случайный словарь из списка и выводите то, что Вам нужно. Обновил ответ.